# Remove trailing zeros after decimal point in DB2

Tags: db2, text-parsing

I have the following values in label table in DB2 (version : 9.5.8)

`select field4 from label with ur`

```
1.5000
0.006
9.0001
104.2500
17.0000
3.5000
```

Is it possible to eliminate the trailing zeros after the decimal point with an update query in DB2?
If all the digits are zeros after the decimal point, I need to keep that as `.0`, however.

Expected output:

```
1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5
```

Comment: What is the data type of `field4`? If it's numeric, you'd need to modify the format to your liking in the query instead of trying to change it in the database.

Comment: Its varchar2. But I don't want to change the column format

Comment: `VARCHAR2` is an Oracle proprietary data type, you said you were using DB2. And why are you storing numbers in a character column?

Comment: sorry, it's character

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider changing the column to some kind of numeric. Anyhow, heres an idea:

```
with t(s) as (
    values '1.5000', '0.006', '9.0001','104.2500','17.0000','3.5'
) 
select translate(rtrim(translate(s,' ','0')),'0',' ') 
    || case when translate(rtrim(translate(s,' ','0')),'0',' ') like '%.' 
       then '0' 
       else '' 
       end 
from t
```

1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5

Using a CTE for translate(rtrim(translate(s,' ','0')),'0',' ') will minimize the number of function calls.

```
with t(s) as (values '1.5000', '0.006', '9.0001','104.2500','17.0000','3.5')
   , u(s) as ( 
        select translate(rtrim(translate(s,' ','0')),'0',' ') 
        from t 
     ) 
select s || case when s like '%.' then '0' else '' end 
from u
```

1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky, but it should work for you.

```
SELECT
    trimmed || CASE WHEN LOCATE('.',trimmed) = LENGTH(trimmed) THEN '0' ELSE '' END
FROM (
    SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM field4) AS trimmed
    FROM lablel
) A
```

The `CASE` statement re-adds a trailing zero if a decimal is the last character. If your string contains other decimals for whatever reason, this would break. If you were on DB2 9.7 (I'm assuming LUW here), then a better option would be to use [`LOCATE_IN_STRING`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054098.html), which can work backwards from the end of the string when you provide a negative start:

```
SELECT
    trimmed || CASE WHEN LOCATE_IN_STRING(trimmed,'.',-1) = LENGTH(trimmed) THEN '0' ELSE '' END
FROM (
    SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM field4) AS trimmed
    FROM lablel
) A
```