# Remove zeros after two decimal places

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to remove zeros after two decimal places in DB2. I have more than 1000 rows for this column

For example

3.6900 needs to be converted to 3.69

I used cast in the query after my research and it gave me the correct result but I would like to understand what is DECIMAL(12,2) and how does this work ? Is there any better way to eliminate zeros?

```
SELECT  CAST(CG.RATE AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS test from fd.OFFERS CG
```

Please let me know.

Comment: `DECIMAL(12, 2)` allows decimal numbers with a maximum of `12` digits, `2` of which after the decimal point. I. e., all decimal numbers are truncated after two decimal places, regardless of whether they are followed by zeros or other digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020574/remove-trailing-zeros-after-decimal-point-in-db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020574/remove-trailing-zeros-after-decimal-point-in-db2)?

Comment: @Scriptim :Thanks for the clarification. In my case, I can allow maximum of 4 digits right and its not required to allow 12 digits?  CAST(CG.RATE AS DECIMAL(4,2))

Answer (score 1):

> what is DECIMAL(12,2) and how does this work?

The DECIMAL data type represents numbers with a specified decimal precision. You can read [a description of the numeric data types](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/the-numeric-data-type-of-db2/):

> A DECIMAL number is a packed decimal number with an implicit decimal point. The position of the decimal point is determined by the precision and the scale of the number. The scale, which is the number of digits in the fractional part of the number, cannot be negative or greater than the precision. The maximum precision is 31 digits.